# I am resampling daily data and aggregating my data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am a beginner with python. I am trying to resample and aggregate daily data so I can get the sum and mean for different columns. But notice when the result come in the sum or mean are either too high or too low.

`Example :

```
# Read in CSV file
climate_df = pd.read_csv("perth_climate_9021.csv",
                         header = None,
                         skiprows = [0,],
                         engine = 'python',
                         names = ['station', 'datetime', 'daily_rain',
                                    'daily_rain_source', 'max_temp', 
                                    'max_temp_source', 'min_temp',
                                    'min_temp_source','evap_pan',
                                    'evap_pan_source'],
                         usecols = ['datetime', 'daily_rain',
                                    'max_temp', 'min_temp',
                                    'evap_pan'] ,
                         parse_dates = ['datetime']
                         )
climate_df = climate_df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(climate_df['datetime']))
climate_df.rename(columns={'datetime':'year_month'}, inplace=True)
# Resample to month start: same data, except index is month start instead of month end
# climate_df = climate_df.sort_index().resample("MS").apply(lambda ser: ser.iloc[-1,])
climate_df1 = climate_df.groupby([climate_df['year_month'].dt.year, climate_df['year_month'].dt.month]).agg({"daily_rain" :'sum', 
                                                                                                           "max_temp" :'mean',
                                                                                                             "min_temp" :'mean', 
                                                                                                             "evap_pan" :'sum'})
```

Snippet of csv file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwDqw.png)

Comment: perhaps you want to standarize/normalize the data. Google for data normalization.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your csv?